# laravel Prevent foreach loop from repeating same results

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Am doing a loop where a product can have many sizes so I display the name of the product and its 1st size and the name of the same product again with its 2nd size but anytime i try, it repeats both sizes on both product names. For example:

I want Product 1 = small, Product 1 = medium but in this case it displays...

Product 1 = small medium, Product 2= small medium. How do I solve this. Below is my blade;

```
 @foreach ($productProductOptions as $productProductOption)

    @foreach($productProductOption->product->options as $productOptions)    
           <tr> 
                <th>{{ $loop->iteration }}</th>

                <td>{{ $productProductOption->product->title }}</td>

                <td>{{ $productOptions->name }}</td>
           </tr>

    @endforeach 

 @endforeach
```

Below is my controller code which am passing to the view;

```
   $productProductOptions = ProductProductOption::all();
```

This is the picture of the table am displaying the items inside...https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/H9UulFq.png

Comment: can you share the model code also looks like you are calling two methods $productProductOption->product->options

Comment: I have make changes to my question above and the image link. Kindly check it out. Thank you for your help

Comment: this is my `product_product_options` table....https://pasteboard.co/Ha0HUBS.png

Comment: Can you share model code from which model you are calling the method ->product->options

Comment: In the `ProductProductOption` Model
    
        public function product()
            {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'product_id');
            }

Comment: So you are calling a method called product which is fine.what is ->option ???

Comment: options refers to a table which contains the sizes of the product

Comment: `public function options()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ProductOption', 'product_option_id');
    }`

Comment: so you want to show only 1 product with 1 size, as if you are showing the products size categories? like the case of Jumper clothing medium, you want it to show only 1 time

Comment: @Hamza exactly... and in the next loop i show the other size of the same product.

Answer (score 0):

### [Distinct()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#selects)

is the function you are seeking, which returns only distinct values from the database, I would suggest updating your controller to send only this specific detail as to save time and gain performance, however it only depends how you show your data and how big is it.

### DB Query

```
$productProductOptions = DB::table('products')
                         ->select('title', 'size')
                         ->distinct()
                         ->groupBy('title')
                         ->orderBy('title', 'asc')
                         ->get();
```

### Eloquent

```
$productProductOptions = ProductProductOption::select('title', 'size')
                         ->distinct()
                         ->groupBy('title')
                         ->orderBy('title', 'asc')
                         ->get();
```